# RewriteCond comparing two variables in Apache htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to have a `rewritecond` that gets `true` if two variables `HTTP_ORIGIN` and `HTTP_HOST` are equals. I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Origin} ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}(/|$)
```

But despite Netbeans syntactic color, it appears that Apache is not replacing `%{HTTP_HOST}` by its value. I guessed it because

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Origin} ^http://cnfr005554(/|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =cnfr005554
```

Works.

So how can I test that the two variables `%{HTTP:Origin}` and `%{HTTP_HOST}` are equals? (and yes, it's for applying OWASP's guidelines to mitigate XSRF)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `RewriteCond` you cannot use a variable on right hand side.

You have to use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}##%{HTTP:Origin} ^(.+)##http://\1(/|$)
```

Here are are joining 2 variables using a delimiter `##` (it can be anything). Then on RHS we match and capture value before `##` that represents `HTTP_HOST`. After `##` using a back-reference `\1` we do our matching.

Comment: Ah, I knew I would have to use these back-reference, but I did not remember the name & syntax of these. Thanks ! One more question: what if `##` appears in the host or in the origin? are Apache regex greedy?

Comment: I know that, but proxy's mess struggling/discarding the HTTP request did not help... Sorry for the delay !

Comment: This answer is a bit old, but is there a way to negate this test? I need to match if two variables are _not_ equal. I've tried using ! on either side of the second set, but it hasn't done what I would expect.

Comment: @anubhava - I already have, actually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088734/negative-comparison-of-variables-in-apache-rewritecond Thanks for responding