# Negative Comparison of Variables in Apache RewriteCond

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a Rewrite block that aims to with redirect users to a URL that reflects their locale, if they aren't already. This seems to require me to compare two variables, which I realize is a little tricky in a RewriteCond, but there's gotta be a way to do this elegantly instead of having several different rules.

Basically - if I'm here but shouldn't be (because of geofencing), redirect to the identified path.

```
# Snip several SetEnvIf rules for the UserLocale variable used below

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(us|au|uk|eu)/$
# This is where I'm having trouble. 
# This following condition should evaluate whether the requested URI matches the StoreLocale
RewriteCond %{ENV:UserLocale} !%1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%{ENV:UserLocale}/ [R=302,L]
```

I know there's some syntax about [combining two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871983/rewritecond-comparing-two-variables-in-apache-htaccess), but I haven't been able to get a negative test here.

Comment: So `RewriteRule` should fire when `%{ENV:StoreLocale}` is NOT `%{REQUEST_URI}`? Also what is logic behind `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(us|au|uk|eu)/$` ?

Comment: Yes. Essentially it's: "If the requested URL is `/(us|au|uk|eu)/`", then if the captured fragment does NOT match the defined `StoreLocale` (e.g. I'm requesting /`eu`/ but StoreLocale is `us`)", then redirect to the URL that contains the StoreLocale. (Note: It might make more contextual sense to think of 'StoreLocale' as 'UserLocale'. I'll update)

Comment: So value of `%{ENV:UserLocale}` is `/us/` or it is just `us` ?

Comment: `UserLocale` would be 'us', 'au', 'uk', or 'eu'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:UserLocale}#$1 !^([^#]+)#\1$
RewriteRule ^(us|au|uk|eu)/$ https://example.com/%{ENV:UserLocale}/ [R=302,L,NC]
```

This will be effectively this code:

```
if ( %{ENV:UserLocale} != $1 ) {
   RewriteRule ^(us|au|uk|eu)/$ https://example.com/%{ENV:UserLocale}/ 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @anubhava! That's kind of a crazy regex above, any chance you'd be willing to explain that a bit?

Comment: Actually not that crazy. On LHS we combine `%{ENV:UserLocale}` and `$1` values with a delimiter as `#`. Then on RHS we match and group part before `#` into group #1. The we back-reference it using `\1` after `#` to ensure we have same value before and after `#`. Presence of `!` negates whole conditions thus giving us effect of `%{ENV:UserLocale} != $1 ` condition.